# How pass object to jquery callback?

Tags: javascript, ajax, object, jquery-callback

I have this code:

```
function API() {
    this.status = 'nothing';
}

API.prototype.search = function() {
    this.status = 'searching';

    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.com',
        data: {shapeFormat: 'raw'},
        dataType: 'json',
        timeout: 11000,
        success: this.OK_callback,
        error: this.KO_callback
    });
}

API.prototype.OK_callback = function(data) {
    console.log(this.status); // How to pass this value to the function?
}

API.prototype.KO_callback() {
    this.status = 'done';
}
```

How could I access to `this.status` value insie `OK_callback`?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invoke your function in proper context. The simple is to use [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.com',
    data: {shapeFormat: 'raw'},
    dataType: 'json',
    timeout: 11000,
    success: this.OK_callback.bind(this),
    error: this.KO_callback.bind(this)
});
```

or you can use [context](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) setting to set callback context:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.com',
    data: {shapeFormat: 'raw'},
    dataType: 'json',
    timeout: 11000,
    success: this.OK_callback,
    error: this.KO_callback,
    context: this
});
```